# How to use Selenium to get AJAX comment's replies?

Tags: python, ajax, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am learning and trying to collect arguments from [this website](http://www.debate.org/opinions/is-global-climate-change-man-made). I am using BeautifulSoup and Selenium to do this.

Now I can collect all the arguments but the replies of the comments. To view the replies, we need to click on the red arrow (View Replies). Note that not all the comments contain replies.

In my mind, there are two solutions that I can think of:

1.As hilighted in green colors, I notice that each argument contains unique ID (aid). I need Selenium to click on the red arrow so that the replies are listed. But how can I navigate to the View Replies? I know only the aid and the View Replies has the same tag name.

2.Use Selenium to click all View Replies in all comments then use BeautifulSoup to get values in the tags. I think the second option is easier. The following code is what I am doing for the second option:

```
while True:
    try:
        wait3 = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
        btn_view_reply =   wait3.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "msg-contain")))
    btn_view_reply.click()

    wait4 = WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
    loadReply = wait4.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"msg-contain")))

    content = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML;")
          
except TimeoutException:
    break
```

The problem is Selenium will not move to the next View Replies button. Could you please give some suggestion on this? Thank you.

## [image: Comment's replies]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a different approach:

- explicitly wait for posts to appear
- for each post (`aid` attribute uniquely identifies a post):

  - check how many replies are there
  - if there are replies:

    - click on the link
    - explicitly wait for a reply to appear
    - parse replies

Implementation:

```
from pprint import pprint
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.debate.org/opinions/is-global-climate-change-man-made')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

# wait for posts to load
posts_xpath = '//div[@id="debate"]/div/ul/li[@aid]'
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, posts_xpath)))

# collect posts data
posts = []
for post in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(posts_xpath):
    aid = post.get_attribute('aid')
    contents = post.find_element_by_tag_name('p').text

    replies = []

    # check how many replies are there
    reply_count = int(post.find_element_by_class_name('m-cnt').text)
    if reply_count > 0:
        post.find_element_by_class_name('msg-contain').click()

        replies_xpath = '//li[@aid="{aid}"]//div[@class="comment-container"]//div[@class="comment"]/div[@class="comment-body"]'.format(aid=aid)
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, replies_xpath)))

        for reply in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(replies_xpath):
            replies.append(reply.text)

    posts.append({'contents': contents, 'replies': replies})

pprint(posts)
```

This produces the following output:

```
[{'contents': u'If we have never had been here, then the earth would have gone on healthy and the way it should, but since we are here there are disruptive thing on the earth that are causing the destruction on the earth. And most of these factors are man made, if not all are man made',
  'replies': [u"Only 8% of the world's CO2 comes from humans though..."]},
 {'contents': u"Yes, I know the temperature changes, but that's natural, it happens another way... now there is a lot of CO2 in the air, the long-wave radiation increases and the heat gets trapped. Greenland is partially melting. Why is it melting now? Well, I guess it kind of melted before, but still, why is it melting more than other times? I have to go with man-made, I need more proof that it is a natural cycle, this time.",
  'replies': [u'The trash we burn and we burry is causing that to happen so its just going to melt']},
 {'contents': u'The most prominent reason is that most of the energy we depend on is coming from the fossil fuels and its burning produced carbon dioxide, the main cause for global climate change. Another reason is that forests are disappearing because of many purposes for human life. Without strong change in our energy source and use, global climate change will get worse.',
  'replies': []},
  ...
 {'contents': u'Solar flares happen on a systematic basis. There are varying degrees of these flares. When these low, medium, and high impact flares happen at the same time an incredibly large amount of bad chemicals are released and cause more impact than human activity. An example is if the low impact flares happened every two years, the medium impact may happen every four years and the high impact may happen every eight years so they would collide quite often.',
  'replies': []}]
```

You would still need to improve the solution to handle that "Load more Arguments" button at the bottom in order to extract more arguments, but this should give you a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you very much @alecxe. It is really awesome. What I have done was the mixed BeautifulSoup and Selenium. So it was confused. Now I have solution. Thank you. For the "Load More Arguments", I use the explicit methods as you suggest. It works well.

Comment: @theteddyboy glad to help and thanks for a clear question and interesting challenge.